# How to identify/find self-created variables in iPython session?

Tags: ipython, matplotlib

Scenario:
I often work in 'pylab' mode of iPython for interactive data analysis. During these sessions I create many intermittent variables and sometimes I forget what I have called things, especially if an analyis session is running for several days (obviously with interruptions).

Now the problem is, that with the dir() command one sees all defined variables in this iPython session, but because it's a pylab session, many important numpy and matplotlib commands are in the global namespace and it's basically hopeless to find my own defined variables in this huge list.

Is there any way to filter this for 'imported' ones and created ones so that I can see only the variables that I have manually created during this session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ipython's magic function %who should do the job.

Comment: On a side note, it's just `who`  (or `%who` if auto-magic isn't turned on) when you're in an ipython shell.  (Calling it directly won't work)

Comment: who() would just call numpy.who() as this is in a pylab session. %who does the job, unfortunately I need to use the % even so auto-magic is on, because of the pylab session, where an empty 'who' would link to the numpy.who function.